# How to convert user input to Integer?

Tags: string, haskell, integer, converters

Libs.hs:

```
...
--COMBINED FUNCTION TO VALIDATE A CREDIT CARD NUMBER

validateCard :: Integer -> Bool
validateCard x = compute x `mod` 10 == 0
    where
      compute :: Integer -> Integer
      compute = addNumbers . subDoubles . doubleNumber . cardNumber

--DISPLAY USER MSG IF CARD IS VALID OR NOT
isValid card
  | card == True = "This is a valid credit card!"
  | otherwise = "This card is invalid"
```

Main.hs:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn "Please enter a credit card number:"
    input <- getLine
    isValid $ validateCard (read input :: Integer) --Converted to an Integer
```

So i have this piece of Haskell code. The problem is that the function takes an Integer but a user input returns a String ([Char]). I have tried converting it into an Integer using the the `read` function but that matches [Char] with expected type IO (). Basically i have no clue how to transform a user input from a String to an Integer. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you want an `Integer`, why did you specify that `read` should give you an `Int` instead of an `Integer`?

Comment: `isValid` just returns a `String`. What do you want to happen with that string?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica because i was wondering if it was easier to go from int to integer. I have changed the post to reflect how i orignally converted it but the error still occurs

Comment: The conversion part looks fine – it’s the `isValid` part that doesn’t. You need an `IO ()`, like the one produced by `putStrLn`. Try giving `isValid` an explicit type to help you along, and maybe a better name.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica i want to display the string to the user in the console using `isValid`

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica thank you, after i put `putStrLn` in front of the strings in `isValid` it compiles and returns correctly

Comment: You don't need the annotation on the call to `read input`; since `validateCard :: Integer -> String`, the type check knows that `read input` must return an `Integer`.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the type of your `isValid` function: it's `Bool -> [Char]`.

The compiler will tell you

> `Couldn't match type ‘[]’ with ‘IO’`

`main` is an IO, so you can't use a non-IO value there. If you want to print that string returned by `isValid`, you just need to pass it to `putStrLn`:

```
putStrLn $ isValid $ validateCard (read input)
```

No need to specify the type of the `read` call, the type of `validateCard` lets the compiler infer it.

Note that when you have a very short monadic code like that, sometimes you can choose to write it in point-free style, without the variable:

```hs
    main = do
      putStrLn "Please enter a credit card number:"
      fmap (isValid . validateCard . read) getLine >>= putStrLn
```

Answer (score 0):

A credit card number is not, in fact, a number. It's a short sequence of digits. You can represent that using e.g. [Int], although that does allow an infinitely long credit card number and digits greater than 9 or lower than 0. To get a `[Char]-> [Int]`, you can use `map` and a `Char-> Int`. Using Hoogle, I found `Data.Char.digitToInt`.

You can hopefully trust your user to enter a finite credit card number, and `subDoubles= flip mod 10`, combined with no more than one digit fitting into a character, should keep digits in the range `[0..9]`. Oh, and in the end you'll probably want to report the result back to the user using `putStrLn`.